# setting up page tabs on more than one page I admin

Tags: tabs, facebook-canvas

Ok I have my main account then I have several pages, I did an app / page tab , and it works and shows up on the correct page. Now I want to do another app for another page I admin. How do I tell the app what page to be on? when ever I attempt to make a new one it makes me login as me. So then I see the first app and when I add a new app I do not see where to tell it what page to be on. All the apps will be stored on one domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You ca do the following as described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

As a Page Tab App developer, you can prompt users to install your Page Tab App by including an "Install this Page Tab App" link that explicitly directs the user to the /dialog/pagetab endpoint, either within your Page Tab App or Website:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL
```

where YOUR_APP_ID and YOUR_URL can be found in your app settings.

This will help you add any app to a page tab.